# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libbcg729.so.0" not found pjsip

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, pjsip, pjsua2

i am trying to build pjsip app for android using pjsip version 2.7 with g729.
I am able to build g729 libraries using cmake and pjsip is able to recognize it.And i successfully built the so file.
And i kept the sofile in jnifolder named armeabi-v7a.
But the pjsip sample app is not even able to launch it throws this following exception

```
Process: org.pjsip.pjsua2.app, PID: 13121                                                                      java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libbcg729.so.0" not found                                                                          at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:372)                                                                          at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1076)                                                                          at org.pjsip.pjsua2.app.MyApp.<clinit>(MyApp.java:295)                                                                          at org.pjsip.pjsua2.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:132)
```

I followed this link exactly but it shows this error??
how to fix it??
https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/ticket/2029